# Yew tree taking moisture

Tags: trees

Next door has a large yew tree 30ft which is taking moisture from my lawn. How do I retain the moisture in the lawn. Thanks

Comment: What is the problem that you see?  What is the type of soil you have?

Comment: have you looked into having 1-2 inchs of wood chips with grass growing through them? it will help aerate your soil, and help water infiltrate. If you inoculate your yard with wine caps first you'll get 2 great results (healthy lawn, and food).

Comment: Can you add a picture of the lawn so we can see the problem?